# Understanding why negative lookahead is not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say I have this url:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbm=isch&randomParameters=123

I want to match google's search url, when it doesn't contain:

> tbm=isch
>
> tbm=news
>
> param1=432

I've tried this pattern:

```
^http(s):\/\/www.google.(.*)\/(search|webhp)\?(?![\s]+(tbm=isch|tbm=news|param1=432))
```

but it's not working (as in still matching), the sample url

Comment: @CinCout It's still matching, even though it shouldn't

Comment: `[\s]+` - why? Did you mean `.*?` or `[\S]*?`

Comment: In what language/library are you trying to use this regexp?

Comment: @MariaDeleva I deleted my comment by mistake. That was it. Not sure how I overlooked it. If you create an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: To help you "understand" as the title says - your regex only tests the first field in the query string. And the negative look ahead starts by checking spaces, which never will match = match for the negative look ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
^                         # anchor it to the beginning
https?://                 # http or https
(?:
    (?!tbm=(?:isch|news)) # first neg. lookahead
    (?!param1=432)        # second
    \S                    # anything but whitespace
)+
$                         # THE END
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qB7dR2/2).
There might be builtin-methods like `urlparse()` for your specific programming language though.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should be

```
^https:\/\/www.google.([^\/]*)\/(search|webhp)\?(?!.*(tbm\=isch|tbm\=news|param1\=432)).*$
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/mP6sJ0/1)

The issue was that you were trying to do lookahead with `\s*` instead of `.*` which will match any number of characters.

Also `www.google.(.*)` would have caused a lot of backtracking causing performance issue so I have replaced it with `www.google.([^\/]*)`

---

**Edit**

Am wondering why you are using regex for this instead of simple indexof or similar methods from the language you are using. Any special usecase here??

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `[\s]+` to `.*?` or `[\S]*?` and your regex will work. To also match the whole url, if it fits the criteria, you can add another [\S]* at the end:

```
^http(s):\/\/www.google.([\w\.]*)\/(search|webhp)\?(?![\S]*?(tbm=isch|tbm=news|param1=432))[\S]*
```